# Django: request.POST.get from form data not working correctly

Tags: django, python-3.x, forms, post

I have been trying to come up with a solution and have been searching the web for hours now. I hope you guys can help me find the problem in my code!

I am trying to implement a form in Django, a simple textfield. As soon as the user submits the text data in the field, I want it to POST the data and I want a next view to retrieve that data and print it on screen. In detail: I want the user to enter some text in the form on page home.html then submit it, and the user input will then be printed on the next page predict.html (of course, I am planning to transform the inpur in between, but first I want the text to at least get printed on the second page).

This is my code:

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import NameForm
from django.template import RequestContext

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'personal/home.html')

def predicted(request):
    predicted = request.POST.get('data')
    return render(request, 'personal/predicted.html', {"predicted": predicted})

def get_name(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            return predicted(request)
    else:
        form = NameForm()
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'form': form})
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

class NameForm(forms.Form):
    data = forms.CharField(label='Your text:', max_length=100)
```

**home.html**

```
{% extends "personal/header.html" %}
{% block content %}
<p>Please input your text:</p>
<br>
<form action="/predicted/" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="data">Your text: </label>
    <input id="data" type="text" name="data">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit!">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

**predicted.html**

```
{% extends "personal/header.html" %}
{% block content %}
<p><a>Your predicted text:
<br>
    {{ predicted }} </a></p>

{% endblock %}
```

I guess the error lies somewhere in the `predicted = request.POST.get('data')` line in combination with some other line I wrote wrongly... Except for that, everything else seems to work fine. I would like to keep the method POST (not GET) since the data in the input form can become quite large, and this will result in a hughe URL for predict.html.

Thank you so much in advance for your help!!

Comment: You pass it as `predicted` to the template, not as `x` nor as `data`.

Comment: Oh sorry about that! I was "debugging" and forgot to remove... Even with {{ predicted }} the output is empty, so that is not the main problem here... But thanks for highlighting, I edited.

Comment: Does your code currently throw any errors when you access the prediction page?

Comment: No, it all works fine, but it is empty where {{ predicted }} should be, so no variable is taken over.

Comment: Rather than this `return render_to_response('personal/predcited.html',  RequestContext(request))` why don't you use  just `return predicted(request)`?

Comment: That definitely makes sense, thank you! I implemented that, but still {{ predicted }} is not showing up :-(

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to come up with a solution that works. I don't know if this is the prettiest solution, but I'm happy it works. Everything in my code was correct, except for the **views.py** file. I made a mistake when querying the POST data. The data in POST is stored in a QueryDict. I didn't realize this and used the wrong function for querying the data. I changed the code in the predicted function to:

```
QueryDict = request.POST 
predicted = QueryDict.get("data")
```

And now it suddently works and displays the data on the next html page.
Here is my full code in the **views.py** file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.http import HttpRequest
from .forms import NameForm
from django.template import RequestContext

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'personal/home.html')

def about(request):
    return render(request, 'personal/about.html')

def predicted(request):
    QueryDict = request.POST
    predicted = QueryDict.get("data")
    return render(request, 'personal/predicted.html', {"predicted": predicted})

def get_name(request):  
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            return predicted(request)
    else:
        form = NameForm()
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'form': form})
```

Thanks to everyone in the comments for the tips. In case anyone knows a more detailed explanation to what my mistake was, I would love to hear!